# MSI Laptop dGPU driver/recognition?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card, nvidia-geforce

I have a MSI GE62 6QD Apache Pro with a NVIDIA GEFORCE GTX 960M dGPU, running a clean installation of Windows 10 v1909.

I am trying to get Windows to recognize the dedicated NVIDIA GTX 960M graphics card, with no success. Since I couldn't find drivers for the graphics card on [MSI's website](https://www.msi.com/Laptop/support/GE62-6QF-Apache-Pro.html#down-driver&Win10%2064), I downloaded them from [their NVIDIA page](https://www.geforce.com/drivers/results/155645). When I try to install the drivers using setup.exe, I get this error:

```
NVIDIA Installer cannot continue

This NVIDIA graphics driver is not compatible with this version of Windows.
This graphics driver could not find compatible graphics hardware
```

I have tried re-downloading the driver installer and restarting the computer.

I have also tried emailing MSI, but they never got back to me. Lastly, I have created an account for register.msi.com, but they give me an error when I try to register the laptop using its S/N.

Update:

I was able to access the account that the laptop was registered to. I got support over an online chat, and after doing everything that they told me to do and more (resetting the EC, the bios, wiping and then installing Windows again, and pushing the button on the bottom of the laptop that you have to use a paper clip to push), without any success. Furthermore, the Ethernet has stopped working, and SteelSeries software can't connect to the keyboard, even after removing and then (re)installing the software and drivers.

---

Final update:

Today the dGPU just showed up in Device Manager, and I was able to install the NVIDIA 960M driver successfully. I have no idea what caused it to suddenly work, I hadn't done anything to it or that would affect it.

Comment: The proper Nvidia drivers should be downloaded from Windows Update.  What version of Windows do you have installed?  Edit your question to include this extremely vital information

Comment: @Ramhound I updated the question

Comment: You are sure you downloaded the [441.66 - WHQL](https://www.geforce.com/drivers/results/155645), are running `Windows 10 version 1909`, and actually have an `NVIDIA GEFORCE GTX 960M` GPU?  What drivers from Windows Update are downloaded for your display device?

Comment: Yes, I am sure that I downloaded the 441.66 WHQL (I linked the page that I found it at in the question). I got the windows version from system information, and I'm pretty sure that I have a NVIDIA GEFORCE GTX 960M GPU, as that's the GPU that MSI says the laptop comes with (it's a 6th gen I believe). I don't know how to check what drivers are installed, but if you tell me how to check I can create a comment with them tomorrow.

Comment: Commenting just to say that there's a Nvidia driver in the MSI page you linked, just expand "VGA" and you'll see both Intel and Nvidia graphics drivers. Nvidia's driver is v.373.06. But the newer version you download should install as well because it's the current recommendation at Nvidia's for your card. Considering the release date of the v.441.xx I would expect it to be compatible with the latest Windows build so not that either but, at this point, I would try an older version just in case.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia if the NVIDIA GPU was working, wouldn't it show up as an unknown device?

Comment: Are you saying it doesn't show up in device manager? Some firmwares allow disabling the dGPU, Could it be that it's disabled and the drives refuses to install because of that?

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia yes, it won't show up in device manager. There's nothing in the BIOS that mentions disabling or enabling the dGPU, so how would I theoretically enable it? There happens to be a tiny button on the motherboard that you have to use a paper clip to push (as there's a tiny hole in the bottom case to access it). Could this be something related to the GPU?

Comment: You *may* have some other related setting, please check your user's manual (it should be available online). If there's none your dGPU is probably defective.

Comment: The user manual on MSI's website didn't say anything about that, as far as I could see. If the dGPU is dead, that's really unfortunate as the motherboard has had to be replaced 2-4 times already in the laptop's ~3.5 year lifespan, and I won't replace it again, knowing that it'll just fail again and then cost me another $800-$1200.

Comment: @Sam - If the driver on the MSI website does not work, then it sounds like the dGPU, is indeed not functional.  When was the last time the GPU worked?  I checked the MSI website for the laptop, I know for a fact there is an Nvidia driver on the page for your laptop, it's out of date but it exists.